# ViewHolder's data has been bound but why aren't the widgets updating?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

Our MainActivity's TabLayout instantiates this Fragment, which has a RecyclerView with each individual item being a CardView. Data is retrieved from a backend server and updates the Adapter. The Adapter binds to the ViewHolder and the ViewHolder should update each CardView's widgets with the server's data.

This is the vision but the ViewHolder isn't updating the CardView's TextView widget. It still displays the default hardcoded value from the layout xml.

To test, I added breakpoints and Log statements within the Adapter and the ViewHolder and stepped through. All looked fine.

Everywhere I put the Log statement, it logged the correct data.

If data binding seems fine and there are no other errors then why doesn't the ViewHolder's bindModel method update the TextView?

```
public class ModelsFragment extends Fragment {

private final String API_KEY = "INSERT API KEY HERE";

private static final String ARG_CATEGORY = "model_category";
private String mCategory;

private RecyclerView mModelRecyclerView;
private ModelAdapter mModelAdapter;

private List<Model> mModels;

public static Fragment newInstance(String category) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_CATEGORY, category);
    ModelsFragment modelsFragment = new ModelsFragment();
    modelsFragment.setArguments(args);

    return modelsFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mCategory = getArguments().getString(ARG_CATEGORY);

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity(), R.style.ProgressDialogTheme);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar);
    progressDialog.show();

    EdmundsService service = EdmundsServiceGenerator.createService(EdmundsService.class);

    Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();
    options.put("state", "new");
    options.put("year", "2016");
    options.put("view", "basic");
    options.put("api_key", API_KEY);
    if (mCategory != null) {
        options.put("category", mCategory);
    }

    // Use the hash map to actually query the backend API server with a GET request.
    Call<Models> call = service.getModels(options);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Models>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Models> call, Response<Models> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                mModels = response.body().getModels();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                updateUI();
                Log.i("GET Status", "Successfully retrieved data");
                Log.i("GET Status", response.body().getModelsCount().toString());
            }
            else {
                Log.i("GET Status", "Failed to retrieve data");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Models> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Error retrieving data", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mModelRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_models, container, false);
    mModelRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mModelRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    updateUI();

    return mModelRecyclerView;
}

private void updateUI() {
    mModelAdapter = new ModelAdapter(mModels);
    mModelRecyclerView.setAdapter(mModelAdapter);
}

public class ModelHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private Model model;
    private TextView mName;

    public ModelHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
        super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_models_card_view_item, parent, false));
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_models_card_view_item, parent, false);

        mName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view_name);
    }

    public void bindModel(Model model) {
        this.model = model;

        // This if statement added to prevent null object reference errors.
        if (this.model != null) {
            // Data correctly logged. 
            Log.i("Inside IF statement", this.model.getName());

            mName.setText(this.model.getName()); // Why doesn't this update?
        }

        // Data correctly logged.
        Log.i("Bound model", String.valueOf(this.model.getName()));
    }

}

public class ModelAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ModelHolder> {
    // Set number of Cards in the recycler view.
    private List<Model> models;

    public ModelAdapter(List<Model> models) {
        this.models = models;
    }

    @Override
    public ModelHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ModelHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ModelHolder holder, int position) {
        // For our list of models, get one model by position and bind it to our view holder class.
        Model model = models.get(position);

        Log.i("Just prior to binding", model.getName());

        holder.bindModel(model);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return models == null ? 0 : models.size();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try running `updateUI()` on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inflating 2 views in your `ModelHolder`

```
public ModelHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
        super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_models_card_view_item, parent, false));
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_models_card_view_item, parent, false);

        mName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view_name);
    }
```

The view you pass to the super call is the view you are displaying. The View you are inflating after that is not being displayed (and is what you are using to find `mName`) which is why you aren't seeing changes. You should only be inflating one view and passing it into the `ModelHolder` so you can search for your `R.id.card_view_name` view.

Ex.

```
public ModelHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view_name);
    }
```

and in the adapters onCreateViewHolder

```
@Override
public ModelHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_models_card_view_item, parent, false);
    return new ModelHolder(view);
}
```